# Setting Variable Inside Post on Successful Request Across the Controller

Tags: ios, swift, post, global

I'm getting really frustrated so I'm just posting it because I'm sure there's an easy answer but it makes no dang sense.

I have this request to load products from a database
`self.fetchFlashDealsWebServiceCall()`

That request then sets my products, and only returns 10 at a time due to pagination from the server

What's frustrating me is I need to know the max pages, and it's returned in the request, and I set it in the request, and I understand that completions can make it so variables aren't set properly sometimes but the products load, the variables are set properly, and it's just this one gosh dang property that won't set. I have tried a lot of options, and I'm just at the end of my rope with this stupid variable. I've verified it IS set properly inside of `status` but everywhere else (including at the end of the fetchDataFromServer) it is nil. I could set it to not be optional but that means I have to set it inside of the viewDidLoad function and that won't work either because I have to wait for the request to know.

Set the variable under the ViewController with `var maxPages: Int?`

Fetch Request

```
webService_obj.fetchDataFromServer(alertMsg: false, header:headerTxt, withParameter: PostData as NSDictionary, inVC: self, showHud: false){ (response,message,status) in
            if status{
                let data = response.value(forKey: "data") as! [String: Any]
                let totalPages = data["totalPage"]
                self.maxPages = totalPages as? Int
                
               self.homeBannerData = data["baner"] as! [[String : String]]
                self.imagesbanner =  self.homeBannerData.map{ $0["image"]!}
                
                if self.currentPageNumber == 1 {
                    self.productData = data["product"]  as! [[String:String]]
                } else {
                    self.productData.append(contentsOf: data["product"] as! [[String : String]])
                }
                self.isPageRefresing = false
                
           
            } else {
                self.productData = []
            }
            
            if self.productData.count > 0 {
                self.lbl_no.isHidden = true
            } else {
                self.lbl_no.isHidden = false
            }
            
            print("maxPages == \(self.maxPages) in Fetch Request")
            
            self.collectionview_list.reloadData()
        }
```

JSON Response from Server

```
{
        baner =         (
        );
        currentPage = 1;
        product =         (
                        {
                "company_name" = "Sea Dubai";
                created = "51 week ago";
                discount = "";
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/342b590dc317e6db9eecef09f5b52b05.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/342b590dc317e6db9eecef09f5b52b05.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/db95783b008b8a557af4c06a213711da.png";
                name = "WOW Watersports- Go Bot 3 Rider Towable Tubes";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-31-69";
                price = "360.00";
                productViewStatus = "";
                "product_id" = 356;
                "product_variant_id" = 455;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 135;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "Sea Dubai";
                created = "51 week ago";
                discount = 5;
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/fb7d00c06eb24d20f4fdd59724fab5b9.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/fb7d00c06eb24d20f4fdd59724fab5b9.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/db95783b008b8a557af4c06a213711da.png";
                name = "Combined Rope with Chain Forerunner / Stainless Steel";
                "offer_end_date" = "03-28-22";
                price = "151.50";
                productViewStatus = "";
                "product_id" = 355;
                "product_variant_id" = 454;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 135;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "Empire Marine International L.L.C";
                created = "51 week ago";
                discount = 8;
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/972ca4126da90706c2b22a4821f3672d.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/972ca4126da90706c2b22a4821f3672d.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/8a3555b6b16b3d52c7ac33268e10fb8d.jpg";
                name = "SEAGO Horseshoe Lifebuoy with bracket and SOLAS light";
                "offer_end_date" = "03-23-22";
                price = "56.70";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 354;
                "product_variant_id" = 453;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 134;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "Empire Marine International L.L.C";
                created = "51 week ago";
                discount = "";
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/9d394e91f531d04cf2cd8c518cf2144f.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/9d394e91f531d04cf2cd8c518cf2144f.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/8a3555b6b16b3d52c7ac33268e10fb8d.jpg";
                name = "WINDEX XL Wind Direction Indicator";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-31-69";
                price = "129.00";
                productViewStatus = "";
                "product_id" = 352;
                "product_variant_id" = 450;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 134;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "Empire Marine International L.L.C";
                created = "51 week ago";
                discount = "";
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/f4257738fe7f103ab5c61cceb531c075.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/f4257738fe7f103ab5c61cceb531c075.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/8a3555b6b16b3d52c7ac33268e10fb8d.jpg";
                name = "Transom Platform, stainless steel / teak with foldable ladder";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-31-69";
                price = "345.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 349;
                "product_variant_id" = 447;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "2 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 134;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "AER\U00c9 DOCKING SOLUTIONS";
                created = "13 Jan 2022";
                discount = "";
                "fixcost_product" = n;
                image = "uploads/product/image/5cd42aac8aec881886610a2a67ba6081.jpg";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/5cd42aac8aec881886610a2a67ba6081.jpg";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/3dfd2934bc97e0d297c0e89f239703b5.png";
                name = "Fruit request";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-31-69";
                price = "0.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 348;
                "product_variant_id" = 446;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "4 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 88;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "USA PARTS AND MORE";
                created = "25 Oct 2021";
                discount = 0;
                "fixcost_product" = n;
                image = "uploads/product/image/711a624e07059edba464ab50f7480103.png";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/711a624e07059edba464ab50f7480103.png";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/89bd178a5695c8ec82e0259ef73f79ca.jpg";
                name = "624610 FRIGIDAIRE door ";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-10-22";
                price = "0.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 347;
                "product_variant_id" = 445;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 167;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "USA PARTS AND MORE";
                created = "25 Oct 2021";
                discount = 0;
                "fixcost_product" = n;
                image = "uploads/product/image/b01409071ed51eaf9601d5c461eabd30.jpg";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/b01409071ed51eaf9601d5c461eabd30.jpg";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/89bd178a5695c8ec82e0259ef73f79ca.jpg";
                name = "624432 WHRILPOOL switch";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-10-22";
                price = "0.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 346;
                "product_variant_id" = 444;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 167;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "USA PARTS AND MORE";
                created = "25 Oct 2021";
                discount = 0;
                "fixcost_product" = n;
                image = "uploads/product/image/20d78421ece6efe54b8247b8788c9a5b.jpg";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/20d78421ece6efe54b8247b8788c9a5b.jpg";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/89bd178a5695c8ec82e0259ef73f79ca.jpg";
                name = "624425 BROAN valve";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-10-22";
                price = "0.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 345;
                "product_variant_id" = 443;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "0 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 167;
            },
                        {
                "company_name" = "USA PARTS AND MORE";
                created = "25 Oct 2021";
                discount = 0;
                "fixcost_product" = y;
                image = "uploads/product/image/7397d3151fd357f9c4a4ddcae49c690f.jpg";
                "image_thumb" = "uploads/product/thumb/7397d3151fd357f9c4a4ddcae49c690f.jpg";
                logo = "uploads/user/thumb/89bd178a5695c8ec82e0259ef73f79ca.jpg";
                name = "624404 SAMSUNG igniter";
                "offer_end_date" = "12-10-22";
                price = "123.00";
                productViewStatus = "New Releases";
                "product_id" = 344;
                "product_variant_id" = 442;
                rating = 5;
                "rating_count" = 0;
                totalSold = "1 Units Sold";
                "user_id" = 167;
            }
        );
        totalPage = 6;
    };
    "error_message" = "";
    status = OK;
    "status_code" = 200;
    "success_message" = success;
}
```

If I print `totalPages` it's `Optional(6)`
then if I print `self.maxPages` after setting it it's nil

Comment: Try to print the content of `totalPages` after it is set. Also, do you have the response from the web service as text? would be good to know what's actually included in that response

Comment: @bbjay added JSON data, I've verified the response is in fact able to set the total pages, it's set to `Optional(6)` so I unwrap it to maxPages and it supposedly sets it by `self.maxPages = totalPages as? Int` but then it's nil by the end of the dang function

Comment: So typecasting it to int is what's making it nil?

Comment: don't think so. What's the value when you set it like `self.maxPages = totalPages ?? 1`

Comment: `let totalPages = data["totalPage"] -- self.maxPages = totalPages as? Int ?? 5 -- print("totalPages == \(totalPages)") -- print("self.maxPages == \(self.maxPages)")` and it's Optional(5) so casting the `Optional(6)` as Int is causing it to become nil

Comment: I literally just used `if let totalPages = totalPages { print(totalPages)` and it prints 6. But it is using `Any` type for it, sooooooooooo. Then I convert the `Any` type to `Int` and it's nil. Smashing my head into the keyboard.

Comment: hmm, what's with `self.maxPages = Int(totalPages)` ?

Comment: Idk, I've tried a lot of things. The only thing that worked was typecasting it to a string first and then typecasting *that* to an Int. super annoying. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more "robust" and safer way to parse that value:

```
    let tp = data["totalPage"]
    if let t = tp as? Int {
        print("Setting as Int")
        self.maxPages = t
    } else if let t = tp as? String, let n = Int(t) {
        print("Setting as Int(String)")
        self.maxPages = n
    } else {
        print("Failed to parse data[\"totalPage\"]")
        self.maxPages = 0
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I would agree that's the "best" way to do it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

So apparently Swift is just idiotic sometimes and I had to typecast the (clearly) Int value to a String with the following

```
let totalPages = data["totalPage"]
if let totalPages = totalPages as? String {
    self.maxPages = Int(totalPages)
}
```

and that worked to give the `Optional(6)` value to my int. Single most frustrating thing that doesn't make **any** sense to me that I've ever dealt with but hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You should **always** safely unwrap optionals... You should also understand what data type the code is producing. See this snippet: https://pastebin.com/2hhjEExx

Comment: @DonMag I knew what data type the code was, and I knew what it was returning, and I also knew that it *was* setting it to 6 inside of an unwrap, but what was frustrating was that despite it setting it to 6 inside that unwrap using `if let totalPages = data["totalPage"] { use value }` it still returned nil or showed nil after. Which is probably because it's still an optional int but frustrating nonetheless

Comment: Zach ... see my answer for (what I consider) a better approach.

Comment: I would agree with you, thank you